# Как прочитать данные из буфера?

Tags: c++

Мне необходимо как-то прочитать данные из буфера, а также узнать размер каждого слова (то есть до пробела) и в вести каждое слово в отдельный индекс в Массиве.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, что бы прочитать данные из буфера обмена нужно использовать WinApi функцию: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098185/how-can-i-assign-clipboard-text-to-a-variable-in-c

Касательно разделения подсчета каждого слова, можно воспользовать решениями из этого вопроса по разделению строки по делителю(В данном случае пробел) и делить считать в каждом слове длину : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c